# How to import image using nextjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, image, next.js

I created an array off object using in and i want to import an image stored in my laptop folder to my project . This is a next.js prpject i am working on . How do i properly import an image in my laptop folder in next.js
The image is in the src folder , not in my public folder .
Thank you for your time

```
const data = {
    products: [
      {
        _id: '1',
        name: 'Nike Slim Shirt',
        category: 'Shirts',
        image: '/../img/shoes/men/luis/2',
        price: 120,
        brand: 'Nike',
        rating: 4.5,
        size: 10,
        description: 'high quality product',
      },
      {
        _id: '2',
        name: 'Adidas Fit Shirt',
        category: 'Shirts',
        image: '/../img/shoes/men/luis/2',
        price: 100,
        brand: 'Adidas',
        rating: 4.0,
        size: 10,
        description: 'high quality product',
      },
      {
        _id: '3',
        name: 'Lacoste Free Shirt',
        category: 'Shirts',
        image: '/../img/shoes/men/luis/2',
        price: 220,
        brand: 'Lacoste',
        rating: 4.8,
        size: 17,
        description: 'high quality product',
      },
      {
        _id: '4',
        name: 'Nike Slim Pant',
        category: 'Pants',
        image: '/../img/shoes/men/luis/2',
        price: 78,
        brand: 'Nike',
        rating: 4.5,
        size: 14,
        description: 'high quality product',
      },
      {
        _id: '5',
        name: 'Puma Slim Pant',
        category: 'Pants',
        image: '/../img/shoes/men/luis/2',
        price: 65,
        brand: 'Puma',
        rating: 4.5,
        size: 10,
        description: 'high quality product',
      },
      {
        _id: '6',
        name: 'Adidas Fit Pant',
        category: 'Pants',
        image: '/../img/shoes/men/luis/2',
        price: 139,
        brand: 'Adidas',
        rating: 4.5,
        size: 15,
        description: 'high quality product',
      },
    ],
  };
  export default data;
```

Comment: I'd recommend you move all static assets to the public folder, and benefit from Next.js [Static File Serving](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving). Otherwise, the relative paths you're using for the images paths will vary based on where you're importing the images from.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to note:

- Next uses [Webpack](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/custom-webpack-config) to build your application server-side. The URL paths must be imported as ES modules so that when Webpack modifies your files, the new URLs can be inserted correctly into your application.
- If you are [serving static files](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving) they must be located in the `/public` folder in the root of your application.

Example of modified code:

```js
import LuisImg from '/public/shoes/men/luis/2'

const data = {
    products: [
      {
        _id: '1',
        name: 'Nike Slim Shirt',
        category: 'Shirts',
        image: LuisImg,
        price: 120,
        brand: 'Nike',
        rating: 4.5,
        size: 10,
        description: 'high quality product',
      },
      {
        _id: '2',
        name: 'Adidas Fit Shirt',
        category: 'Shirts',
        image: LuisImg,
        price: 100,
        brand: 'Adidas',
        rating: 4.0,
        size: 10,
        description: 'high quality product',
      },
      {
        _id: '3',
        name: 'Lacoste Free Shirt',
        category: 'Shirts',
        image: LuisImg,
        price: 220,
        brand: 'Lacoste',
        rating: 4.8,
        size: 17,
        description: 'high quality product',
      },
      {
        _id: '4',
        name: 'Nike Slim Pant',
        category: 'Pants',
        image: LuisImg,
        price: 78,
        brand: 'Nike',
        rating: 4.5,
        size: 14,
        description: 'high quality product',
      },
      {
        _id: '5',
        name: 'Puma Slim Pant',
        category: 'Pants',
        image: LuisImg,
        price: 65,
        brand: 'Puma',
        rating: 4.5,
        size: 10,
        description: 'high quality product',
      },
      {
        _id: '6',
        name: 'Adidas Fit Pant',
        category: 'Pants',
        image: LuisImg,
        price: 139,
        brand: 'Adidas',
        rating: 4.5,
        size: 15,
        description: 'high quality product',
      },
    ],
  };
  export default data;
```